# Unable to install package (pcapy) in python

Tags: python, package

I recently started to code in python and I have some issues with the the package installer. I installed python 3.4 with brew (because I use mac os x yosemite) then i did : "pip3 install pcapy" in the terminal then this error comes up:

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/b_/5vj9c7095xgfh8f6rdmhm85r0000gn/T/pip-build-wsmcyf_y/pcapy

Thank you for any answer.

Comment: pcapy - http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy isn't very up to date, there is a chance python 3.4 is not compatible with it - try to use pip of 2.7 to see if it works

Comment: thanks @nrathaus as you said it works with python 2.7